# How to find all prolog rules in database

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a facts db filled with at least:

```
fact1(A) :- !, A=ok.
fact2(B) :- !, B=ok.
```

How can I enumerate through all the facts in this db?  Ideally I'd have a predicate that I could use:

```
?- all_rules( Head :- Tail).
Head=fact1(_G100),
Tail=(!, _G100=ok) ;
Head=fact2(_G101),
Tail=(!, _G101=ok)
....followed by all other predicates in other modules loaded...
```

I found [current_predicate/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_predicate/1), but I can't figure out what this is actually doing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the precise Prolog system you are using. As long, as you only want to look at the definitions, `listing/0` works in many systems. But `listing/0` only prints a text. `clause/2` often works only for predicates declared dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this:

```
?- current_predicate(Name/Arity),
   functor(Pred, Name, Arity),
   nth_clause(Pred, Index, Ref),
   clause(Head, Body, Ref).
```

Read more in [Examining the program](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.15%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/examineprog.html%27%29%29).

Comment: consider `functor(Pred, Name, Arity)`

Comment: clause/2 is exactly what I'm looking for!  In this example, I believe calling it with clause(Head, Body) would give me Head=fact(A), Body=(!,A=ok)